# Programmatic way to download tabular data

Tags: looker-studio

There is an instruction to download data from Data Studio's chart [here](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7398375?hl=en), but it's based on UI interaction. Is there an easy programmatic way to download tabular data as CSV?

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no programmatic way to download chart data.